# How to go up a directory in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm coming from windows were there is a designated button to do this.  Just click it and you can go "up" a directory.

I can no find a way to do this in macOS using Finder.

I'm running macOS - Mojave.

I'm using Finder 10.14.4.

[Screeenshot hosted on Imgur per SuperUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrByb.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though I don't usually use keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd> will move you up one directory in icon view.

There is also a back arrow but that takes you back in your directory tree history.

Comment: That works, but it opens a new window.  Can I assume there is no GUI based way to do this in the same window?

Comment: not that I am aware of but then I don't *use* those kind of keyboard shortcuts, so perhaps someone else knows.

Answer (score 27):

If you open a Finder window, near the bottom is the list of the window's directory structure. See the image below.

[image]

Double-Click on any of the folders/directories in the list and Finder will go to that location.

Comment: The directory path is not shown by default; to show it, choose View menu > Show Path Bar.

Comment: **Double-click** on the directory in the Path Bar to go to that location.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd> will move up a directory without opening a new tab in finder.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>▲ Up Arrow</kbd> - Navigates to **Enclosing Folder**

Previous answers maybe were right in the past but currently on Sonoma it have changed a bit.

---

### To figure out current combination

1. Focus  **current finder window**.
2. In the **menu** Click **Go**
3. Next to the menu entry **Enclosing Folder** current keyboard combination is shown